# How to build a java client to read streaming response from JAX RS based REST service?

Tags: jax-rs, http-streaming

I'm building a REST service using JAX RS StreamingOutput to stream chunks of data as soon as they become available.  Now the problem is on my java client calling this service.  What's the best way to make it works in a event driven model - as soon as each chunk is returned, client process that chunk and send it to presentation.

I think Ning client might be of some help:
http://www.ning.com/code/2010/03/introducing-nings-asynchronous-http-client-library/

Has anyone done something like this before?  Dose Netflix's RxJava have some good pattern for this?

thanks
chuck